Trouble updating borders in Google Spreadsheet via C#
I'm having difficulty updating the borders in a Google Spreadsheet using C# and Google's API. I have authorized access to the sheet and can update the cell contents. I just can't figure out what I'm missing. I modelled my attempt after this example.
Here is my code:
public void FormatTest()
{
    Request request = new()
    {
        UpdateBorders = new()
        {
            Range = new()
            {
                SheetId = 0,
                StartRowIndex = 3,
                EndRowIndex = 3,
                StartColumnIndex = 0,
                EndColumnIndex = 5
            },
            Bottom = new()
            {
                Color = new()
                {
                    Blue = 1
                },
                Style = "DASHED",
                Width = 1
            },
            InnerHorizontal = new()
            {
                Color = new()
                {
                    Blue = 1
                },
                Style = "DASHED",
                Width = 1
            }
        }
    };

    var batchRequest = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest()
    {
        Requests = [request]
    };

    var update = service.Spreadsheets.BatchUpdate(batchRequest, ScheduleSheetId);
    var response = update.Execute();
}

When I check the spreadsheet, there's no change, although there's no error either, making me think I've simply left some property unset.

Well, as always, I find the answer immediately after I grow frustrated enough to post a public question. The issue was with my range. I had assumed that the GridRange parameter worked like A1 notation, where applying to rows 3-3 would simply apply to row 3:
StartRowIndex = 3,
EndRowIndex = 3

Instead, it ignores the last row in the range and applies to each preceding row. For example:
StartRowIndex = 3,
EndRowIndex = 5

This will apply the update to the cells in rows 3 and 4, but crucially not row 5. I hope this helps someone!

It may be that the topmost border is actually drawn in row 3. The code appears to draws borders at the bottom of cells, so a border drawn in row 3 will appear below the contents of those cells.

@doubleunary You're absolutely right. I've been playing around with this a lot since, and it definitely applies from first index (inclusive) to last index (exclusive). I'll edit my answer.
